# Convert GPG private key to QR code?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp, gpg4win

How can I generate a QR code from a OpenPGP/GnuPG private key on Windows 7?

Context:
I created a private key pair on a Windows computer and want to import the key to my phone. The phone app has options: "Import from File", "Scan QR Code".

I think a secure way would be to create a QR code on the computer and use the phone app to scan it.

What I tried already:
There is Windows program called "qrencode-win32" (https://code.google.com/archive/p/qrencode-win32). But it didn't work:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If the result is too large, you need to select a larger QR code.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: On Windows 7 computer